# JS не находит значение по пути объекта. Ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'byId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Работаю со стеком React+Redux. Сейчас имею state с такой иерархией:

[image: Scrin]

В коде пытаюсь обратиться к ключу byId объекта engines, кидает ошибку - 'byId' of undefined.

Причем, когда пытаюсь обратиться просто к engines, например: `console.log(state.data.allData.engines)` - все отлично находит. И внутри лежит allId и byId:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только пытаюсь обратится к byId или allId `console.log(state.data.allData.engines.allId)`  -   ошибка.

Изменения в Redux store:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте везде стереть имя свойства `byId` (вообще по всему проекту) и записать его заново. у меня похожее было, когда не мог взять свойство из объекта, хоть оно там 100% было. понимаю, звучит бредово, но попытайтесь

Comment: ну или на момент обращения свойства `byId` еще нет в `state`

Comment: @Август подбросил отличную мысль. `console.log` выводит текущее состояние объекта и если объект изменился, то и вывод `console.log` изменится. Ради интереса попробуйте вместо `console.log(state.data.allData.engines)` вывести `console.log(JSON.stringify(state.data.allData.engines))`. Так вы выведете состояние объекта и оно уже не изменится в консоли со временем если в engines будут добавлены новые поля.

Comment: да, обратите внимание, что возле объекта в консоли есть уведомление в виде буквы **i** в фиолетовом огранке. оно свидетельствует о том, что объект буквально недавно изменился (что-то вроде *Object value has been changed*, что-то вроде этого). наведите курсором на это уведомление и прочтите описание

Comment: @sneas Проверил через JSON, все также выводится. За лайфхак спасибо, пригодиться.

Comment: @Август Поменял свойство byId на byid (у меня весь state нормализует данные через одну функцию, поэтому это легко сделать) все та же ошибка(
State в этот момент точно есть, так как этот компонент вызывается несколько раз и когда state еще нет, консоль лог выдает undefined

Comment: @mr.smile, окей. посмотрите тогда изменения в *ReduxDevTools*. если у Вас его нет, то подебажте через эту функцию `store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));`. напишите, присутствует ли свойство `byId` при каждом изменении `state`

Comment: @Август добавил скрин изменений стора. Там по сути один запрос и success. Все. На этапе запроса, конечно же, byId нету

Comment: а ну скиньте github Вашего проекта

Comment: @Август https://github.com/NikitaVagin/calc-blp

Comment: @Август причем я пытался дебажить консоль-логом по всему пути: от получения  данных до reducer. Везде можно достучаться до объекта byId, везде кроме функции mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, при первом рендере компонента в state не было byId, поэтому была ошибка.

Решением было "глубже" инициализировать **исходный** state. Было:

```
const initialState:initialStateType = {
        allData: {},
        error: null,
        loading: true

}
```

Стало:

```
const initialState:initialStateType = {
        allData: {
                materials: {},
                engines: {},
                fasteningCover: {},
                optionsForBoat: {},
                optionsForEngine: {}
        },      
        error: null,
        loading: true

}
```

Comment: мои поздравления. не забудьте засчитать свой ответ правильным (поставить галочку), чтобы официально закрыть эту проблему

Comment: @Август спасибо за помощь!